# Identification of Bug/Insect (with picture)

Tags: entomology

[image]

What is this insect?

I’ve seen a lot of them indoors. The most distinctive characteristic is that single, orange dot in the middle of the back. The picture was taken in Louisiana, USA.

Comment: Further information: I’m currently located in Louisiana. I’ve seen a lot of them indoors and they’re quite small if you can see from the comparison to the baking soda box.

Comment: What is the approximative size in standard units (not everybody is used to the size of Arm Hammer baking soda box)? Can you get a better picture (a better view of the thorax may help)?

Comment: I'll try to get a better picture. They're quite small. This one was by far the largest at probably around a centimeter long. All the others I've seen were a fraction of the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [**cockroach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockroach), probably a [**German cockroach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_cockroach) nymph.

Cockroaches are well-known pests. According to the Wikipedia link above, there are about 4600 species of cockroaches, 30 of them are associated with human habitats. Cockroaches are extremely resistant and are able to survive in a wide range of environmental conditions.

[image]

@PhysicalFatness pointed out that [German cockroach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_cockroach) nymphs look very much like your picture and it is likely the species that you've found. Don't be fooled by its name German cockroaches are found all over the world, not only in Germany.

[image]

Comment: You actually may be right. https://citybugs.tamu.edu/blatella-nymph/ It looks a lot like a German cockroach nymph.